# working with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Summary: How to use Japanese key word in where condition. For ex:

```
select * from tbl_Mst_Product_Language  where Name = N'闲云舒展'
```

Here in above query in where condition I have used Japanese keyword which is working fine. But I want to put this value in variable as I need to pass this from c#.

Problem I am facing is where I am trying to put where conditon in variable . For example

```
declare @test as nvarchar(max)
set  @test = '闲云舒展'
select * from tbl_Mst_Product_Language  where Name =  @test
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem then? Just do that. Please explain where you are stuck, since, as it is stands now, this is not a question.

Comment: `set @test = '闲云舒展'` might be better as `set @test = N'闲云舒展'`

Answer (score 2):

Where you have:

```
declare @test as nvarchar(max)
set @test = '闲云舒展'
select * from tbl_Mst_Product_Language where Name = @test
```

Try:

```
declare @test as nvarchar(max)
set @test = N'闲云舒展' -- Note here, N
select * from tbl_Mst_Product_Language where Name = @test
```